# StreamTokenizer Behavior for division operator "/"

Tags: java, string, eof, stringreader

Take a look at the demo code for StreamTokenizer [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/streamtokenizer.html). It doesn't seems to work properly when there is `/` in string(Just add `/` in between string in `StringReader`). Here is the code from mentioned link,

```
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(
    new StringReader("Mary had 1 little lamb..."));

    while(tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){

        if(tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
            System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
        } else if(tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
            System.out.println(tokenizer.nval);
        } else if(tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

For example, for string `"Mary had 1 little lamb..."`, output is

```
Mary
had
1.0
little
lamb...
```

For string, `"Mary had 1 /little lamb..."`, output is

```
Mary
had
1.0
```

- Does `/` work as EOF token? If so, why?
- Is there any way to distinguish `/` as a different token other than EOF.

Comment: Seems OK to me. Can you share a code snippet, the output you're getting and the output you expect?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Note: [`StreamTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) is deprecated.

Comment: I've edited the question. You may find more details now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#StreamTokenizer(java.io.InputStream)), `/` is the comment character in a `StreamTokenizer`. Everything that comes after it, until an EOL or EOF will be ignored and won't be tokenized.

E.g., to continue the example you've given, if the string is `"Mary had 1 / 2\n little lamb..."`, `2` is commented out and won't be tokenized, and the tokenization will resume after the `\n`. So the output would be:

```
Mary
had
1.0
little
lamb...
```

Comment: @Mureinik That is very good answer buddy :) . May be downvoters expected more (i'm not sure what)

Comment: @Mureinik: What is preferred way in which I can parse and print `/` as a separate token? One way is to replace `/` with some string which we are sure will not going to come in original string, and in if-else condition check and replace that particular string back with `/`. But this doesn't seem elegant way. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Just Adding to above answer 
.Since `/` is a comment character in StreamTokenizer and continue until the end of the line. Hence you have to add either a new line `\n` or `\r` in the String 
So `"Mary had 1 / \n little /\nlamb..."` or 
`"Mary had 1 / \r little/\rlamb..."` both will work for you